# Distinct roots of function

Tags: calculus

A continuous function $f$ defined on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ assumes positive and negative values in $\mathbb{R}$ then the equation $f(x) = 0$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$ for example, if it is known that a continuous function f on  $\mathbb{R}$ is positive at   some point and its minimum value is negative then the equation $f(x) = 0$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$

Consider $f(x)=ke^x-x$ for all values of $k$.

**Question 1(Multiple choice question)**

The positive value of $k$ for which $ke^x-x=0$ has only one root

A) $\frac{1}{e}$ (B) 1 (C) e (D) $\ln2 $

**Question 2 (Multiple choice question)**

For $k>0$ the set of values of $k$ for which $ke^x-x=0$ has two distinct root

A) $(0,\frac{1}{e})$ B) $(\frac{1}{e},1)$ C) $(\frac{1}{e},\infty)$ D) $(0,1)$

P.S:
**Question 3 (Multiple choice question)**

The line $y=x$ meets the curve $y=ke^x$ for $k\leq 0$ at

A) no point B) one point, C) two points D) more than two points.

The Answer is $k=0$, $y=0$, $x=0$ which I did by hit and trial, can it be solved by substitution as it has been solved for the first two. Hence it meets at 'one point' Choice 'B'

Comment: What did you try to solve it?

Comment: Actually it is hit and trial question i tried to solve it by graph on computer but the same i could not solve it manually

Comment: @Eugen Covaci I am not able to proceed for Question 1 I only proceeded to 'ln k +x= ln x' for k in the range (0,1) we get 'ln k' negative for k =0 'ln k' is zero and for k>1 'ln k' is positive i am struck after this, I took logarithms of the equation ke^x-x=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k>0$, then
$$f'(x)=ke^{x}-1>0\implies x>\ln(1/k)=-\ln(k).$$
Therefore $f$ is strictly deceasing in $(-\infty-\ln(k)]$ and it is
strictly increasing in $[-\ln(k),+\infty)$.

Therefore $-\ln(k)$ is a global minimum point in $\mathbb{R}$ and the minimal value is
$$f(-\ln(k))=1+\ln(k).$$
Moreover $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)=+\infty$.
What may we conclude about Question 1 and Question 2?

P.S. Note that there is only one root when the minimum value is zero:
$$1+\ln(k)=0\implies \ln(k)=-1\implies k=1/e.$$
For two roots the minimum value should be less than zero:
$$1+\ln(k)<0\implies \ln(k)<-1\implies k\in (0,1/e).$$

P.S. The graphs of $f(x)=ke^x$ and $g(x)=x$ meet at a unique point for any $k\leq 0$. For $k=0$ it is trivial. For $k<0$ we have that $f(x)=ke^x$ is decreasing and $g(x)=x$ is increasing. Moreover $k=f(0)<g(0)=$ and $0=\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)>\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)=-\infty$. Therefore there is a unique intersection point.

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi Substitute $k$ with the given values. For which $k$, the minimal value  $1+\ln(k)$ is zero?
For 2) solve $1+\ln(k)<0$.

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi I edited my answer with more details. Any further doubt?

Comment: For k=$\frac{1}{e}$ we get 1+ln(k)=0 which is correct Choice A

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi Well done. What about question 2?

Comment: For Question 2 the answer is Choice A which is solved

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi What is it? Edit your questio with a P.S. at the bottom.

Comment: This comprehensive question has one more part:The line y=x meets the curve $y=ke^x$ for k≤0 at A) no point B) one point, C) two point D) more than two point. The Answer is k=0, y=0,x=0 which i did by hit and trial, can it be solved by substitution as you did for other two .Hence it meets at 'one point' Choice 'B'

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi  They meet at one point for any $k\leq 0$. For $k=0$ it is trivial. For $k<0$ we have that $f(x)=ke^x$ is decreasing and $g(x)=x$ is increasing. Moreover $f(0)<g(0)$ and $f(-\infty)>g(-\infty)$. Therefore there is a unique intersection point.

Comment: "For two roots the minimum value should be less than zero", I need some clarification on it so that I can solve other type of similar problem

Comment: If a function is negative at $ a $, positive at $ b $ and increasing in between then $ f $ has a unique zero in $(a, b) $. Use this property on the left and on the right of the minimum.